# How to optimize code for a huge number of input(say 200000) in C?

Tags: c, optimization, timing

Alice is playing an arcade game and wants to climb to the top of the leaderboard and wants to track her ranking. The game uses Dense Ranking, so its leaderboard works like this:

1: The player with the highest score is ranked number 1 on the leaderboard.
2: Players who have equal scores receive the same ranking number, and the next player(s) receive the immediately following ranking number.

For example, the four players on the leaderboard have high scores of 100, 90, 90, and 80. Those players will have ranks 1, 2, 2, and 3, respectively. If Alice's scores are 70, 80, and 105, her rankings after each game are 4th, 3rd, and 1st.

I've tried this code which works with 100000 inputs correctly but when working 200000 inputs it's timing out.

```
int* climbingLeaderboard(int scores_count, int* scores, int alice_count, int* alice, int* result_count) 
    {
        //here scores array is sorted in descending order
        //and alice array is sorted in ascending order

        int rank[scores_count];
        int i, j, temp;

        //inserting rank in rank array according to the scores of scores array
        rank[0] = 1;
        temp = scores[0];
        for(i=1;i<scores_count;i++)
        {
            if(scores[i] == temp)
                rank[i] = rank[i-1];
            else
            {
                rank[i] = rank[i-1] + 1;
                temp = scores[i];
            }
        }

        //Now finding the rank of alice's scores and 
        //reusing the alice array to store the required rank

        for(j=0;j<alice_count;j++)
        {
            //case 1: if alice's score is the lower 
            //than the lowest score of scores array
            if(alice[j] < scores[scores_count-1])
                alice[j] = rank[scores_count-1] + 1;

            //case 2: if alice's score is greater 
            //than the highest score pf the scores array
            else if(alice[j] > scores[0])
                alice[j] = 1;

            //case 3: when alice's score is in between the max-min range    
            else
            {
                for(i=0;i<scores_count;i++)
                {
                    if((alice[j] > scores[i]) || (alice[j]) == scores[i])
                    {
                        alice[j] = rank[i];
                        scores_count = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        *result_count = alice_count;

        return alice;
    }
```

Comment: Rather than a linear search with `for(i=0;i<scores_count;i++)
                {
                    if((alice[j] > scores[i]) || (alice[j]) == scores[i])...`, use a binary search (as `scores[]` is sorted).  It is also possible that   the unposted formation of the sorted `scores[]` is   inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code

```
int binarySearchModified(int low, int up, int data, int *ar)
{
    int mid;
    while (up >= low) 
    {
        mid = (low + up)/2;
        if(ar[mid] == data)
            return mid;
        if(ar[mid] > data)
            low = mid + 1;
        if(ar[mid] < data)
            up = mid - 1;
    }

    return low;
}
```

as

```
else
{
    scores_count = binarySearchModified(0, scores_count-1, alice[j], scores);
    alice[j] = rank[scores_count];
}
```

in the place of

```
else
{
    for(i=0;i<scores_count;i++)
    {
        if((alice[j] > scores[i]) || (alice[j]) == scores[i])
        {
             alice[j] = rank[i];
             scores_count = i;
             break;
         }
     }
}
```

and this is working fine